# a question about the design Validation using JSF framework

Tags: validation, jsf-2, ejb

In software design sort of way, what is best: checking unique input (e.g username) in the DB using a JSF Validator, or using the Controller (managed-bean).

Apparently, in JSF framework, I can't use @EJB in the Validator, so in case I use the Validator for the checks, then I would have to connect to the DB in another way (jdbc connection or something).
In case I check this one in the Controller, I would have to put some logic that is not necessary a part of the process (for example: createUser method).

So, what is the best way according to the JSF framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Apparently, in JSF framework, I can't use @EJB in the Validator, so in case I use the Validator for the checks, then I would have to connect to the DB in another way (jdbc connection or something).*

That's right. A common workaround for this is to declare and use the validator as a [`@ManagedBean`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedBean.html).

E.g.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped // Can be @ApplicationScoped if it does not hold any state.
public class UsernameValidator implements Validator {

    @EJB
    private UserService userService;

    // ...
}
```

with

```xml
<h:inputText validator="#{usernameValidator.validate}" />
```

or

```xml
<h:inputText>
    <f:validator binding="#{usernameValidator}" />
</h:inputText>
```

Comment: A Primefaces observation: I noticed that using <f:validator> inside <p:inputText> as described in this answer did not work (Null Pointer Exception on the injected EJB). Using the EL expression within the validator attribute of the <p:inputText> as above, however, worked perfectly.